# Xcart coupon code is not updating the cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shopping-cart, x-cart

I am using X-Cart for for creating my shopping cart, when I add the discount code it doesn't update the cart simultaneously. I need to reload the page.

[image: Image is attached]

I have used this coupon extension which comes with Xcart by default. [Here is the link to the Coupon site.](https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Discount_Coupons)

There is no error on console as well, is there something wrong with X-Cart?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to check X-Cart logs for possible errors first.
Looking at php_ and xlite_ logs in the /var/log folder might help you.
Let me know if you find anything there.
Thanks.

Also, you seem to be looking into the manual for X-Cart Classic, while the provided screenshot displays X-Cart 5 checkout form. X-Cart 5 knowledge base is available at http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Home